pdf from pdfkit does not have hyperlinks
I'm trying to generate a pdf with the following code.
import pdfkit
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# ...

# Getting only the content wanted for the pdf 
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="lxml")
pdf_content = str(soup.body.find('div', {'id': 'pdf'})

# Generating a pdf
options = {'enable-local-file-access': ''}
pdfkit.from_string(pdf_content, 'out.pdf', options=options)

And the hyperlinks in out.pdf don't work.
I couldn't find any other options to define related to this problem and I'm just trying to get the <a> tags to properly link to another anchor in the document.
Python 3.10, Ubuntu 20.04, wkhtmltopdf installed properly
